# Update tabBarLabel based on state in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a React Native app with a Navigator. I also have a few screens and a header (common to all screens).

In my header I have a button that toggles the app's language. Passing the language to the Navigator's props I'm able to access it in the screens and translate stuff around.

The only thing I can't change is the `tabBarLabel` property in the `navigationOptions` of each screen.

I've tried to simply write:

```
MyStack1.navigationOptions = {
    tabBarLabel: myGlobalTranslationFunction('MyOriginalLabel1', this.props.screenProps.language)
};
```

But that didn't work.

As a tree, you can think of App being the root of my app, which has a `state.language` passed to the Navigator by:

```
<Navigator screenProps={ {language: this.state.language} }/>
```

In my Navigator.js file, I have, for example:

```
const MyStack1 = createStackNavigator({
    MyScreen1: MyScreenComponent1,
    MyScreen2: MyScreenComponent2,
    MyScreen3: MyScreenComponent3,
});

MyStack1.navigationOptions = {
    tabBarLabel: 'MyLabel1'
};

export default createBottomTabNavigator({
        MyStack1,
        MyStack2
    },
    {
        initialRouteName: 'MyStack1',
        tabBarOptions: {
            showLabel: true
        }
    }
);
```

I think this problem lies in defining that the labels **depend** on the language prop, but I don't know how to do that. I thought about writing an actual class that extends React.Component for the Navigator, but I'm not sure how someone who do that, since the code above was basically the one I got by following the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

What's `react-navigation` version you are using?

You can pass down the translations through `screenProps` of the `Navigator`.

```
<Navigator screenProps={{
  myStack1: i18n._('stack1TabBarLabel'),
  myStack2: i18n._('stack2TabBarLabel')
}}/>
```

And modify how `createBottomTabNavigator` create the component.

```
export default createBottomTabNavigator({
    myStack1: {
      screen: MyStack1,
      navigationOptions: ({ screenProps }) => ({
        tabBarLabel: screenProps && screenProps.myStack1
      })
    },
    myStack2: {
      screen: MyStack2,
      navigationOptions: ({ screenProps }) => ({
        tabBarLabel: screenProps && screenProps.myStack2
      })
    }
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'myStack1',
    tabBarOptions: {
        showLabel: true
    }
  }
);
```